# NHibernate how to use ToFuture in more complex queries

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have following data model [image: DataModel]

I would like to retrieve from database one client with its whole organization structure using nHibernate Future.

I tried something like this:

```
    public DBClient GetOrganizationStructure(long clientOid)
    {
        var f0 = Query().Fetch(x => x.RegisteredAddress).Fetch(x => x.BillingAddress).Fetch(x => x.RegisteredOffices).Where(x=>x.Oid == clientOid).ToFuture();
        var f1 = Session.Query<DBRegisteredOffice>().Fetch(x => x.DeliveryAddress).Where(x => x.Client.Oid == clientOid).ToFuture();
        var f2 = Session.Query<DBDepartment>().Fetch(x => x.Workplaces).Where(x => x.RegisteredOffice.Client.Oid == clientOid).ToFuture();
        var f3 = Session.Query<DBWorkplace>().Fetch(x => x.Expertise).Where(x => x.RegisteredOffice.Client.Oid == clientOid || x.Department.RegisteredOffice.Client.Oid == clientOid).ToFuture();

        var v = f0.ToList();
        return v.First();

    }
```

But when I am working with retrieved data another calls to database are done.

- Selection of Department.RegistredOffice
- Selection of Workplace.RegistredOffice

I am pretty sure I am missing something in using ToFuture(). Can you point me to some relevant web pages and help me with this ToFuture sample?

Thanks

Edit: If using QueryOver you can use following

More verbose:

```
        DBRegisteredOffice registeredOfficeAlias = null;
        DBClient clientAlias = null;
        DBDepartment departmentAlias = null;
        DBWorkplace workplaceAlias = null;

        var query = Session.QueryOver(() => clientAlias)
            .Fetch(x => x.RegisteredAddress).Eager
            .Fetch(x => x.BillingAddress).Eager
            .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.RegisteredOffices, () => registeredOfficeAlias)
            .Where(x => x.Oid == clientOid)
            .Future();

        Session.QueryOver(() => registeredOfficeAlias)
            .Fetch(x => x.DeliveryAddress).Eager
            .Where(x => x.Client.Oid == clientOid)
            .Future();

        Session.QueryOver(() => registeredOfficeAlias)
            .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Departments, () => departmentAlias)
            .Where(x => x.Client.Oid == clientOid)
            .Future();

        Session.QueryOver(() => registeredOfficeAlias)
            .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Workplaces, () => workplaceAlias)
            .Where(x => x.Client.Oid == clientOid)
            .Future();

        Session.QueryOver(() => departmentAlias)
            .Fetch(x => x.Workplaces).Eager
            .JoinQueryOver(x => x.RegisteredOffice).Where(x => x.Client.Oid == clientOid)
            .Future();

        Session.QueryOver(() => workplaceAlias)
            .JoinQueryOver(x => x.RegisteredOffice).Where(x => x.Client.Oid == clientOid)
            .Future();

        return query.First();
```

Less verbose:

```
        DBRegisteredOffice registeredOfficeAlias = null;
        DBClient clientAlias = null;
        DBDepartment departmentAlias = null;

        var query = Session.QueryOver(() => clientAlias)
            .Fetch(x => x.RegisteredAddress).Eager
            .Fetch(x => x.BillingAddress).Eager
            .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.RegisteredOffices, () => registeredOfficeAlias)
            .Where(x => x.Oid == clientOid)
            .Future();

        Session.QueryOver(() => registeredOfficeAlias)
            .Fetch(x => x.DeliveryAddress).Eager
            .Fetch(x => x.Workplaces).Eager
            .Where(x => x.Client.Oid == clientOid)
            .Future();

        Session.QueryOver(() => registeredOfficeAlias)
            .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Departments, () => departmentAlias)
            .Where(x => x.Client.Oid == clientOid)
            .Future();

        Session.QueryOver(() => departmentAlias)
            .Fetch(x => x.Workplaces).Eager
            .JoinQueryOver(x => x.RegisteredOffice).Where(x => x.Client.Oid == clientOid)
            .Future();

        return query.First();
```